# Why does the binary + operator not work with two &mut int?

Tags: rust

```
fn increment(number: &mut int) {

    // this fails with: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&mut int`
    //let foo = number + number;

    let foo = number.add(number);

    println!("{}", foo);
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = 5;
    increment(&mut test);

    println!("{}", test);
}
```

Why does `number + number` fail but `number.add(number)` works?

As a bonus question: The above prints out

```
10
5
```

Am I right to assume that `test` is still 5 because the data is **copied** over to increment? The only way that the original `test` variable could be mutated by the `increment` function would be if it was send as `Box<int>`, right?

Comment: `let foo = number.add(number);` also fails in rust `1.64` as there is not implementation of `impl Add<&mut int> for int`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`number + number` fails because they're two references, not two ints. The compiler also tells us why: the `+` operator isn't implemented for the type `&mut int`.

You have to dereference with the dereference operator `*` to get at the int. This would work `let sum = *number + *number;`

`number.add(number);` works because the signature of add is `fn add(&self, &int) -> int;`

> Am I right to assume that test is still 5 because the data is copied
>   over to increment? The only way that the original test variable could
>   be mutated by the increment function would be if it was send as
>   Box, right?

Test is not copied over, but is still 5 because it's never actually mutated. You could mutate it in the increment function if you wanted.

PS: to mutate it

```
fn increment(number: &mut int) {
    *number = *number + *number;
    println!("{}", number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you show me how I could mutate it from within the `increment` function. Please note: I don't want to return something from the `increment` function. I want to see how to really mutate the passed int.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the forrest for the trees!

Comment: Ok, just one more thing ;-) In this example. Is any of the variables ever stored on the heap? I guess not. It's all happening on the stack and both `test` and `number` just point to the same place in memory *on the stack*. Is that correct?

Comment: @Christoph, almost correct. `test` does not point anywhere, it contains the value itself, but it is a stack variable, yes.

Comment: then how does this work?   ``let t = 4 ;
  println!("{:?}", &t + &t); ``

Comment: @raj, it works because we have impl `impl Add<&i32> for &i32`. Perhaps things changed, after all, it's been 8 years