# Does a for loop operate on references or by value?

Tags: for-loop, rust

This aspect of Rust seems rather bizarre at first, and I'd like to know how `for` typing works in this case.

```
fn sum1(v: &mut Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    // I know I don't mutate v, but that's not the point
    let mut s = 0;
    for e in v {
        s += *e;
        // s += e; <- Err!
    }
    s
}

fn sum2(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let mut s = 0;
    for e in v {
        s += e; // Okay?
    }
    s
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{}", sum1(&mut v));
    println!("{}", sum2(&v));
}
```

At first I was confused as to why it wanted me to dereference in `sum1`. But okay, it's saying `AddAssign<&mut i32>` is not implemented, so I see that `e` is `&mut i32`. That's really awesome for changing `e` on the fly.

But now, with that information, why does `sum2` compile? It seems like `AddAssign<&i32>` is indeed implemented (Which I tested separately), so it's possible that it's using that `AddAssign` method on a `&i32`, but then again it's also possible that `e` is simply `i32`. My question boils down to:

*Is `e` an `i32`, or an `&i32`?*

I don't know enough about references to easily check the difference myself (By using something other than `i32` and checking for crashes). `&i32` is the most logical but I would like to know for sure.

Coming from C, mixing between pointers and values is extremely confusing, and it has already taken me quite a bit to get used to with functions automatically dereferencing/referencing their arguments (which I don't think I've really done yet).

EDIT:

The type could be verified (And answer my question) with [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747136/how-do-i-print-the-type-of-a-variable-in-rust), which is useful to mess around with but doesn't directly answer how for loops work. [What is the exact definition of the for loop in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224927/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-the-for-loop-in-rust) helps a lot, and [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter) talks about a related `IntoIterator` trait that can cause for loop confusion.

Comment: [This here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920968/why-does-the-binary-operator-not-work-with-two-mut-int) looks related, but the answer says just *"the `+` operator is not implemented for `&mut i32`"*. From that answer, it's not clear *why* it's not implemented.

Comment: I can see that `+` is implemented for `&` and not `&mut`, but my question is more about what the type of `e` is in `sum2`. It doesn't appear that Rust has a `typeof` operator to check against.

Comment: *My question boils down to: "Is e an i32, or an &i32?"* — Does [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423) answer your question?

Comment: Hm, it may but moreso I was looking for something with respect to how for loops over vectors and iterators work. My `typeof` reference was a bit misplaced (And turns it into an XY problem if I'm just looking for an answer to "`typeof` in Rust?")

Comment: Then are you looking for [What is the exact definition of the for loop in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27224927/155423)?

Comment: Also related: [What does it mean to pass in a vector into a `for` loop versus a reference to a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036279/155423)

Comment: Argh, SO deleted your comment when I marked it as a duplicate — can you re-comment with the third link you listed? I think it was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, that one was it.